# Javascript unexpected token ] error inside HTML code, how can it be possible?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome

I get this javascript error in Chrome's console `Unexpected token ]` pointing to the middle of raw HTML code, what can it be?
Unfortunately I can't post the whole code, but the only javascript present before line 53 is just included unmodified jQuery and jQuery validation plugin.
The page executes a bunch of JS code after that line, though.
How can I get a JS error in HTML code?

edit: After a bit of debugging, I found out the error came from a JSON.parse(), what threw me off is that the error in chrome pointed to HTML code, which gave absolutely no clue.

[image]

Comment: Do you have a broken Chrome plug-in? Plug-ins are capable of injecting HTML/JS into pages. Check the `Sources` tab to see if something else is loading that you aren't expecting.

Comment: That's the least helpful error message, ever. All I can suggest is to try and run your JS code through JSLint to try and find the mis-matched bracket.

Answer (score 1):

The error suggests that you're probably trying to load your CSS as if it were Javascript.

please confirm the css & js are loaded properly(e.g. type="text/javascript" )

Comment: Yes, they're loaded properly. This was working in the previous version and no CSS was mistakenly added in a <script src> if that's what you mean.

Comment: In that case it is hard to tell without seeing your code. Possible guesses could be:
1. having a id="files[] in html where ending double quote is missing
2. parsing a json string having array of objects with some invalid data

these are just guesses based on your inputs.

Answer (score 0):

The error is actually from a `JSON.parse()` trying to parse malformed JSON.